# How to put labels on each data points in stem plot using matlab

Tags: matlab, label, scatter-plot

so this is my x and y data:

```
x = [29.745, 61.77, 42.57,  70.049, 108.51, 93.1,   135.47, 52.79,  77.91,  116.7,  100.71, 146.37, 125.53]
y = [6, 6, 12,  24, 24, 12, 24, 8,  24, 24, 24, 48, 8]

stem(x,y);
```

so i want to label each data point on my stem plot, this i want output i want:[image]

i edit it using paint, can matlab do this vertical labeling? just what the image look like? please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can! You just need to provide the `rotation` property of text annotations with a value of 90 and it works fine.

Example:

```
clear
clc


x = [29.745, 61.77, 42.57,  70.049, 108.51, 93.1,   135.47, 52.79,  77.91,  116.7,  100.71, 146.37, 125.53]
y = [6, 6, 12,  24, 24, 12, 24, 8,  24, 24, 24, 48, 8]

hStem = stem(x,y);

%// Create labels.
Labels = {'none'; 'true';'false';'mean';'none';'';'true';'hints';'high';'low';'peas';'far';'mid'}

%// Get position of each stem 'bar'. Sorry I don't know how to name them.
X_data = get(hStem, 'XData');
Y_data = get(hStem, 'YData');

%// Assign labels.
for labelID = 1 : numel(X_data)
   text(X_data(labelID), Y_data(labelID) + 3, Labels{labelID}, 'HorizontalAlignment', 'center','rotation',90);
end
```

Which gives the following:

[image]

The last label is a bit high so you might want to rescale the axes, but you get the idea.